Understunding how to find a regular expresion for a regular language

Let $L:=\{ \omega \in \{0, 1\}^* : |\omega|_0 \in 3\Bbb{Z}\}$ where $|\omega|_0$ denote the number of $0$'s appearing in $\omega$ . Find a regular expression for $L$ .

I am studying Automaton Theory and I have found on Internet a simple way to compute Regular expressions which works as follows. First, I wrote a DFA for $L$ which is:
$L$" />
Second, consider the following equation system given by the lines connecting the stages: \begin{array}{cc} a) & q_0 = 0q_1 + 1q_0 + \varepsilon \\ b) & q_1 = 0 q_2 + 1 q_1 \\ c) & q_2 = 0 q_0 + 1 q_2 \end{array}
where $\varepsilon$ denotes the empty word which is given to $q_0$ since it is a final stage. Finally, if we solve $q_0$, we would find a Regular expression. Applying Arden's Lemma on those three equations we obtain:
\begin{array}{cc} a) & q_0 = 1^* 0q_1 + 1^* \\ b) & q_1 = 1^* 0 q_2\\ c) & q_2 = 1^* 0 q_0 \end{array}
Replacing $c)$ on $b)$: $q_1 = 1^* 0 1^* 0 q_0$. Replacing this on $a)$ : $1^* 0 1^* 0 1^* 0 q_0 + 1^*$ , so by Arden's Lemma our Regular Expression would be $(1^* 0 1^* 0 1^* 0)^* 1^*$
I am wondering if this is fine since I am very new in this area and in fact my book does not provides a way to compute Regular expressions for a given Language or Automaton, only explains theory.

The equations should be   $$q_0=\epsilon + 1q_0+0q_2$$  and  $$q_1 =0q_0+1q_1$$ and $$q_2=0q_1+1q_2$$. Now you can solve the equations

@ArnabSeal I think that $q_1 = 0q_0 + 1 q_1 $ is wrong since that implies that the automata also accept the words with $|w|_0 \in 2 \Bbb{Z}$

Here only $q_0 $ is final state. So nothing wrong here. You can watch some videos in youtube for dfa to regular language. It will be clear then.  https://youtu.be/SmT1DXLl3f4?si=PfmB1rt2rmvm_pSg

@ArnabSeal Sorry to say, but superdivinidad is right and your comment is plain wrong.

Your solution is correct. In this very special case, you could guess the answer directly, since the letter $1$ acts as the identity. So you start with $(000)^$ and you insert $1^$ between the occurrences of $0$ to get the result.

@J.-E.Pin Thanks for your comment!
